# TCP receiving extended ASCII or utf-8 characters

Tags: c, tcp, winsock

For inverted question mark `¿` I receive two bytes [-62][-65] but how would i get readable utf-8 or ASCII character encoding?

Comment: "¿" isn't a part of ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *is* the UTF8 code for that character. The [inverted question mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bf/index.htm) is Unicode code point `191` which, in UTF8, is `0xc2:0xbf`.

You're seeing them as signed bytes. For example `-62` signed is `256-62` or `194` unsigned - that's hex `0xc2`.

Similarly, `-65` signed is `256-65` or `191` unsigned - that's hex `0xbf`.

If you want to convert your UTF8 sequence into a code point, you can use the table below.

```
    Range              Encoding  Binary value
    -----------------  --------  --------------------------
    U+000000-U+00007f  0xxxxxxx  0xxxxxxx

    U+000080-U+0007ff  110yyyxx  00000yyy xxxxxxxx
                       10xxxxxx

    U+000800-U+00ffff  1110yyyy  yyyyyyyy xxxxxxxx
                       10yyyyxx
                       10xxxxxx

    U+010000-U+10ffff  11110zzz  000zzzzz yyyyyyyy xxxxxxxx
                       10zzyyyy
                       10yyyyxx
                       10xxxxxx
```

For example, your `0xc2:0xbf` is binary `11000010 10111111` which matches the second case:

```
      11000010 10111111
         |||||   ||||||
         |||\\  //////
         ||| ||||||||
    00000000 10111111  ->  0x00bf  ->  191
```

Answer (score 1):

Those 2 bytes probably *are* UTF-8

For ASCII you would need a specific codepage.

And what exactly is a 'readable' char encoding?

Comment: I know. But everybody is using 8.

Comment: @steve-o : I wasn't confusing things, I made a joke. A bad one apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the byte values in hexadecimal:

- -62 is 0xc2
- -65 is 0xbf

If you look up the [Unicode information](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bf/index.htm) for the glyph in question, you can see that this is, inded, the two bytes that make up the UTF-8 encoding of the inverted question mark glyph.